# How to use "use" keyword for phpMailer inside a php file to avoid unexpected 'use' (T_USE) error

Tags: php, namespaces, phpmailer

Here is my php code for sending confermation email.
when I run this code an error through,

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\www\includes\signup.inc.php on line 52

```
 <?php
    ...................
    ...................
  if (mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
    $email_sent_to = $email;
    $email_sent_from = "mymail@gmail.com";
    $subject = "Verify your Email";
    $smtp_username = "mymail@gmail.com";
    $smtp_password = "mypassword";
    $message = "<a href='http://domain/verify.php?vkey=$vkey'>Register Your Account</a> ";

    //Include required phpMailer files
    require 'PHPMailer.php';
    require 'SMTP.php';
    require 'Exception.php';

    //Define name spaces
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

    //Create instance of phpMailer
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    //Set mailer to use smtp
    $mail->isSMTP();
    //Define smtp host
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    //Enable smtp authentication
    $mail->SMTPAuth = "true";
    //Set type of encryption (ssl/tls)
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
    //Set port to connect smtp
    $mail->Port = "587";

    //Set gmail userName
    $mail->Username = $smtp_username;
    //Set gmail Password
    $mail->Password = $smtp_password;

    //Set content type
    $mail->isHTML(true); 
    //Set email Subject
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    //Set sender email
    $mail->setFrom($emai_sent_from);
    //Email body
    $mail->Body = $message;
    //Add recipient
    $mail->addAddress($email_sent_to);

    //Finally send mail
        if ($mail->Send()){
            echo "Email Send Successfully...!";
        }else{
            echo "Failed to send Email....!";
        }

    //Clossing smtp connection
    $mail->smtpClose();

}


?>
```

I also tried by adding the namespaces at the beginning of the code and after my `if (mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt))` statement but it throws the same error.

Comment: Is your script even within a namespace? It seems not to be, since you're requiring the `PHPMailer` files. Using `use` here doesn't seem to make sense to begin with.

Comment: It's work when I separate only this part into another php file and include it to main file.
But when I directly write the code to my main file it throws error...

Comment: That's impossible. Including a file is the same as copying its contents. If including works, then you either a) did something differently or b) didn't insert this code in the same place where you included the file.

Comment: I inserted my code exactly same place where I include.
I don't know why this shows error.

in my main file there are more than 100 lines code.

Comment: Back to square one: do you even need these `use` statements? You have required all the `PHPMailer` files, so the classes are already available to you. Does your code work normally if you just comment out the `use`s?

Comment: Are you inside a function or a class? Where is this code located? Put the use statements at the top of the file

Answer (score 0):

Change the require and the use  definition

```
//Include required phpMailer files
require 'PHPMailer.php';
require 'SMTP.php';
require 'Exception.php';

//Define name spaces
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

if (mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
    $email_sent_to = $email;
    $email_sent_from = "mymail@gmail.com";
    $subject = "Verify your Email";
    $smtp_username = "mymail@gmail.com";
    $smtp_password = "mypassword";
    $message = "<a href='http://domain/verify.php?vkey=$vkey'>Register Your Account</a> ";

    //Create instance of phpMailer
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    //Set mailer to use smtp
    $mail->isSMTP();
    //Define smtp host
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    //Enable smtp authentication
    $mail->SMTPAuth = "true";
    //Set type of encryption (ssl/tls)
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
    //Set port to connect smtp
    $mail->Port = "587";

    //Set gmail userName
    $mail->Username = $smtp_username;
    //Set gmail Password
    $mail->Password = $smtp_password;

    //Set content type
    $mail->isHTML(true); 
    //Set email Subject
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    //Set sender email
    $mail->setFrom($emai_sent_from);
    //Email body
    $mail->Body = $message;
    //Add recipient
    $mail->addAddress($email_sent_to);

    //Finally send mail
        if ($mail->Send()){
            echo "Email Send Successfully...!";
        }else{
            echo "Failed to send Email....!";
        }

    //Clossing smtp connection
    $mail->smtpClose();

}
```

At the top of your code after the php tag

Comment: Your process is showing nothing but same errors

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\www\includes\signup.inc.php on line 45

Answer (score -1):

It's because you're using a version of PHP that is too old and does not support namespaces. Upgrade to PHP version PHP 5.3 or later, though you should only be using 7.4 at worst as that's [the oldest version currently receiving active support](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php). 8.0 is a good choice.

Convention is to put `use` statements before all others, at the top of your script, which is what all the code examples provided with PHPMailer do. I would also recommend learning how to use composer – what you're doing here is already more complex that doing that, and you're only using one package!

Comment: I checked my php version by: $version = phpversion();
print $version;
My php version is 7.4

I only need this package

Comment: You can confirm whether it's a namespace issue by using an FQCN instead of `use`. Try removing the `use` lines and create your instance with `$mail = new \PHPMailer \PHPMailer\PHPMailer();`.